# React i18next fails to load translation.json as json from django

Tags: reactjs, django, localization, internationalization, i18next

React i18next fails to load translation.json as json. everything is functioning well before I use the build folder

I'm using React / Django.

i18n.js :

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

// don't want to use this?
// have a look at the Quick start guide
// for passing in lng and translations on init

const Languages = ['ar', 'en', 'fr']

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    lng: 'en',
    react: {
      useSuspense: true,
    },
    // the translations
    // (tip move them in a JSON file and import them,
    // or even better, manage them via a UI: https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files#manage-your-translations-with-a-management-gui)
    supported: ["en", "fr", "ar"],
    fallbackLng: "en",
    detection: {
      order: ['path', 'cookie', 'htmlTag', 'localStorage', 'subdomain'],
      caches: ['cookie'],
    },
    debug: true,
    whitelist: Languages,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    nsSeperator: false,
    keySeperator: false,
    backend: {
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

index.js :

```
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
import './i18n';

  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Suspense fallback={(<div className='index__loading'><h2>Loading...</h2></div>)}>
          <App />
      </Suspense>,
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

here's where I switch between languages loginheader.js :

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './LoginHeader.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logout } from '../actions/auth';
import SortIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Sort';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import Alert from './Alert';
// import Drower from './Drower';
import Logo from '../assets/images/logo.png';
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { FormControl, Select, MenuItem } from '@mui/material';
// import LanguageIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Language';
import i18next from 'i18next';
import cookies from 'js-cookie';

const languages = [
  {
    code: 'fr',
    name: 'Français',
    country_code: 'fr'
  },
  {
    code: 'en',
    name : 'English',
    country_code: 'en'
  },
  {
    code: 'ar',
    name: 'العربية',
    country_code: 'ly',
    dir: 'rtl'
  }
]

function LoginHeader({ logout, isAuthenticated }) {

  const currentLanguageCode = cookies.get('i18next') || 'en';
  const currentLanguage = languages.find(l => l.code === currentLanguageCode);
  useEffect (() => {
    document.body.dir = currentLanguage.dir || 'ltr'
    // document.title = t('app_title')
  },[currentLanguage]);

  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const [value, setValue] = useState('English')
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }
  
  const guestLinks = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='loginHeader__right'>
        <div className='middle__header__bx'>
    
          <div className='loginHeader__main__btns'>
            <Link className='loginHeader__loginButton' to='/login'><button>{t('header_login')}</button></Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__signupButton' to='/signup'><button>{t('header_signup')}</button></Link>
          </div> 
        
          <div className='loginHeader__services__dropdown'>
          <button className='dropdown__btn dropdown__services'>{t('header.services')}<ExpandMoreIcon className='services__expand'/></button>
          <div className='dropdown__content dropdown__services__content'>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/visa-assist'>{t('services_visaAssist')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/admission'>{t('services_addmissionOffers')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/application-form'>{t('services_forms')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/premuim-support'>{t('services_premium')}</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* start of lang box */}
        <div className='loginHeader__lang'>
          <div className='loginHeader__lang__bx'>
            <div className='loginHeader__lang__container'>
              <Select
                className='loginHeader__select'
                labelId='select-demo'
                id='language-select'
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                disableUnderline
                variant='standard'
              >
                {languages.map(({code, name, country_code}) => 
                  <MenuItem
                    value={name} 
                    key={country_code}
                  >
                    <button 
                      onClick={() => i18next.changeLanguage(code)}
                      className='loginHeader__lang__btn'
                    >
                      {name}
                    </button>
                  </MenuItem>
                )}
              </Select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* end of lang box */}
        <div className='loginHeader__services__dropdown sortIcon__bx'>
          <SortIcon className='dropdown__btn loginHeader__sortIcon'/>
          <div className='dropdown__content sortIcon__dropdown'>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/premuim-support'>{t('header_dropdown_prem')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/visa-assist'>{t('header_dropdown_visaAssist')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/admission'>{t('header_dropdown_admission')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/request-service'>{t('header_dropdown_requestService')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/contact'>{t('header_dropdown_contact')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/signup'>{t('header_signup')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/login'>{t('header_login')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/guid'>{t('header_dropdown_guide')}</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
        
       </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );

  const authLinks = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='loginHeader__right'>
      {/* <button onClick={logout} className='loginHeader__logout__btn'>{t('header_logout')}</button> */}
        {/* start of lang box */}
        <div className='loginHeader__logged__lang'>
          <div className='loginHeader__lang__bx'>
            <FormControl>
              <Select
                className='loginHeader__select'
                labelId='select-demo'
                id='language-select'
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                disableUnderline
                variant='standard'
              >
                {languages.map(({code, name, country_code}) => 
                  <MenuItem
                    value={name} 
                    key={country_code}
                  >
                    <button 
                      onClick={() => i18next.changeLanguage(code)}
                      className='loginHeader__lang__btn'
                      disabled={code === currentLanguageCode}
                    >
                      {name}
                    </button>
                  </MenuItem>
                )}
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* end of lang box */}
      <div className='loginHeader__services__dropdown loggedin__icon__bx'>
          <button className='dropdown__btn'><SortIcon className='loginHeader__sortIcon logedin__sortIcon'/></button>
          <div className='dropdown__content logged__sortIcon__dropdown'>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/premuim-support'>{t('header_dropdown_prem')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/admission'>{t('header_dropdown_admission')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/visa-assist'>{t('header_dropdown_visaAssist')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/request-service'>{t('header_dropdown_requestService')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/contact'>{t('header_dropdown_contact')}</Link>
            <Link className='loginHeader__menuItem' to='/guid'>{t('header_dropdown_guide')}</Link>
            <button onClick={logout} className='logout__btn'>{t('header_logout')}</button>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );

  return (
    <div className='loginHeader'>
      <div className='loginHeader__left'>
        <Link to='/'><img className='logo' src={Logo} alt='logo'/></Link>  
      </div>
      {isAuthenticated ? authLinks() : guestLinks()}
      <Alert/>
    </div>
  )
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout }) (LoginHeader);
```

debug console network/headers:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/locales/en/translation.json
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: same-origin
Content-Length: 948
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Sat, 02 Jul 2022 13:54:00 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.10.2
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: csrftoken=KKBUsud0hxf0n2XkfSuQw9Hx3RLkHnSTyJHzGL8xyg502fPxxcDab3113rLJxQyu; i18next=en
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

network/preview: You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

network/response :

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png"/><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,700&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><title>Diploman</title><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.1e76e6bb.js"></script><link href="/static/css/main.e38e49bd.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body dir="ltr"><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the translation json files are hosted/hosted as static resources in your Django (WSGIServer) server.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/serving-static-files-wsgi-tercio-a-oliveira

Comment: Adrai, Many thanks brother. to solve the issue I placed the locales folder inside static and all works well. Django reads everything inside this folder as static